# Regex pattern to identify s as last character after vowel

Tags: java, regex, string

I'm trying to create a regex pattern where I can detect if a string ends with an 's'. I want to then delete the 's' from the end of the string, but theres a catch...

I want to delete the 's' if, and only if, the preceding word part contains a vowel NOT IMMEDIATELY before the 's', and the word does not contain another vowel.

So for example, the word 'sales' would become 'sale' because there is a vowel before the 'e' that precedes the 's' at the end of the word.

The word 'examples' -> 'example'

BUT the word 'gas' should stay gas because the only vowel is the one immediately before the 's'.

I have come up with the following:

```
public String removeS(String word) {
        if (word.matches(".*[a|e|i|o|u][.*]s")){
            word = word.substring(0, word.length()-1);
        }
        return word; 
}
```

Now when I input a word like "sales", nothing happens. It just remains the word "sales". I am assuming that is has something to do with the regex pattern I am using to match the string.

I am relatively new to regex, but what I was trying to get with this `".*[a|e|i|o|u][.*]s"` is what I explained above. Match with a string that have some vowel (a,e,i,o,u) before the character immediately before the s at the end of a string. Am i overlooking something here?

Comment: `.*[aeiou].*s` might be better.

Comment: As anndy said; but I still don't understand this condition `I want to delete the 's' if and only if the preceding word part contains a vowel NOT IMMEDIATELY before the 's'`

Comment: Something like `[^aeiou].+[aeiou]s`?

Comment: First, your syntax is completely invalid. The correct way to write the regex you build so far is `".*[aeiou].*s"`, however this won't match the way you want to.

Comment: @Anderology 1) putting `|` in the `[]` means that you are looking to match `|` in the character class too; 2) `[.*]` means "match `.` or `*`" (literally). If you want to match any number of any character, you don't want the `[]`. See [the railroad diagram](http://regexper.com/#.*%5Ba%7Ce%7Ci%7Co%7Cu%5D%5B.*%5Ds) of your regex.

Comment: One more question: How do you want to treat the word "trucks", for example?

Comment: @Will the word trucks should become truck.

Comment: @Enissay sorry that is a bit confusing. There must be a vowel somewhere in the word that is not the second to last character in order to delete the s. So the word 'gas' would not have the s deleted because the only vowel is right before the s. there would need to be another vowel in the word in otder to have the s deleted. Like the word 'sales' there is a vowel 'a' that is not located at the second-to-last spot

Comment: @AndyTurner Love the diagram. Stole link for [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35420982/5221149). Thanks.

Comment: You say "I want to delete the 's' if, and only if, the preceding word part contains a vowel NOT IMMEDIATELY before the 's', and the word **does not contain another vowel**." However the word *sales* **does** contain another vowel (`e`) other than the one that's not immediately before the 's' (`a`), yet you want to trim the 's' off sales. What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest you don't try this, because your list of exceptions will grow, and grow, and grow, and grow, and grow, and grow, ...

For example, the work `stress` would get the last `s` removed, following your rules.

Anyway, here is an enhanced version, that also keep double-`s` intact:

```
str.replaceAll("(?i)([aeiou][a-z]*[a-rt-z])s\\b", "$1")
```

[See regex101 for result](https://regex101.com/r/zD3yZ7/1). Notice how `stress` and `has` are left alone.

Also notice how `wishes` becomes `wishe`, which is wrong. English spelling is too complicated for simple rules like this.

Oohhh I like the railroad diagram Andy Turner gave. [Here it is for this regex](http://regexper.com/#%28[aeiou][a-z]*[a-rt-z]%29s%5Cb).

Comment: This works perfectly. I was using this as a part of another method where I did a check for the SS cases, but this works much better. could you explain the regex you used?

Comment: And `cities`, `knives`.

Comment: @Anderology Click the link to regex101. Upper right has explanation. Is that good enough?

Answer (score 1):

Now, I don't know you details of your use case, only the information provided, but this should work:

```
public String removeS(String word) {
    if (word.matches(".*[aeiou].+[aeiou]s")){
        word = word.substring(0, word.length()-1);
    }

    return word; 
}
```

This matches "zero or more characters", followed by "a vowel", followed by "one or more characters", followed by "another vowel", followed by "s".

You can visualize this [here](https://regex101.com/r/uO1bZ4/1).

Note that this required there to be at least one letter inbetween the two vowels. If you want `sees` to become `see` also, change the `.+` to another `.*`, like [this](https://regex101.com/r/uO1bZ4/2).

Comment: Sure it will. They'll be eaten by the `.*`/`.+`.